# How can I recommend a text when user focus on an input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, text

I have a search box in my page, and I want to recommend some part of my page, when user focus on my search box input, to write something

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
```

I want to recommend the user: Best phones , best 2021 laptops etc...

Comment: You mean you want dynamic auto-completion, like in Google's search bar for instance?

Comment: What you're looking for is "typeahead" or "predictive text", which is out of scope for a simple QA website. Here's a tutorial to get you started: 
https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: There is a w3school example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete

Comment: Thanks for your question, but it looks like you are searching for a solution, not an answer. So please do some research and share your efforts of what you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could catch the "click" event on this field via JQuery (if you can use JQuery) and then show the recommendations.

If the recommendations are fixed text that you don´t need to have in a database, you can have them in a hidden div, and when the user clicks on the search box, turn the div into visible.

Very basic code example with JQuery:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="myAmazingSearchBox">
    </form>

    <div id="recommendations" style="display:none">
        <p>Best phones , best 2021 laptops etc...</p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#myAmazingSearchBox").click(function() {
            $("#recommendations").fadeIn();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```